# Add new XElement to Xdocument

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, nfc

I have the following code, which successfully writes to an XML file. However, it overwrites each time because of the tagRegistry.Save() call being made. How can I add a new XElement to the existing file? At the moment the file is simply overwritten.

```
public void saveTag()
{
    if (File.Exists("/tagRegistry.xml"))
    {
        XElement tagRegistry = XElement.Load("/tagRegistry.xml");
        XElement newTag = new XElement("Tag",
        new XElement("tag", stringUid),
        new XElement("name", desiredName),
        new XElement("latitude", latitude),
        new XElement("longitude", longitude));
        tagRegistry.Add(newTag);

        using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (Stream stream = storage.CreateFile("/tagRegistry.xml"))
            {
                tagRegistry.Save(stream);
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        XDocument tagRegistry = new XDocument(new XElement("SmartSafe"));
        tagRegistry.Element("SmartSafe").Add(new XElement("Tag",
                    new XElement("tag", stringUid),
                    new XElement("name", desiredName),
                    new XElement("latitude", latitude),
                    new XElement("longitude", longitude)));
        using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (Stream stream = storage.CreateFile("/tagRegistry.xml"))
            {
                tagRegistry.Save(stream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't -- the only way is as you've done it, overwriting the existing file.

Comment: Okay, so how do I create a new XML file, containing the old data, with the new data too?

Comment: I have done that at the top of the block in the if statement. How do i add the read data into the new file...? Thank you so much for your help so far

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't see that.  I can't see why that wouldn't work?  You've loaded existing into `tagRegistry`, then added `newTag`.

Comment: It does seem odd. Must be missing something, probably incredibly minor...just irritating! Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Just a suggestion, don't nest `using (...)` statements that way, the preferred standard is to place them under each other without brackets or indentation.

Comment: Thank you - will tidy up once Ive fixed this issue - just copied those statements from a tutorial over on MSDN...sloppy coders ;) Thank you :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void saveTag()
{
    using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        XDocument document;
        XElement tagRegistry = null;

        if (storage.FileExists("/tagRegistry.xml"))
        {
            using(var stream = storage.OpenFile("/tagRegistry.xml", FileMode.Open))
            {
                document = XDocument.Load(stream);
            }

            tagRegistry = document.Descendants("SmartSafe").FirstOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            document = new XDocument();
        }

        if(tagRegistry == null)
        {
            tagRegistry = new XElement("SmartSafe");
            document.Add(tagRegistry);
        }

        XElement newTag = new XElement("Tag",
            new XElement("tag", stringUid),
            new XElement("name", desiredName),
            new XElement("latitude", latitude),
            new XElement("longitude", longitude));

        tagRegistry.Add(newTag);

        using (Stream stream = storage.CreateFile("/tagRegistry.xml"))
        {
            document.Save(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that but still seems to be overwriting the existing file with the new Elements only.

Unfortunately the existingDoc.Save(string) method is not possible on Windows Phone (To my knowledge, i may be wrong)

Comment: It uses streams from isolated storage for io, and uses SmartSafe from the existing file for adding new tags

Comment: Wonderful, Thank you so much.

Thank you everyone else too, really appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible your `File.Exists` call is wrong.  You are storing the file to isolated storage, but reading in from your current running directory.  So you're always falling into the `else` block and writing a new file every time.

Comment: This makes sense, can't believe I missed that. Next question is how I query Isostore for the file?

Comment: [IsolatedStorageFile.FileExists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.fileexists(v=vs.95).aspx)